# How can I add <br /> label after every enter/new line in a form

Tags: php, javascript, newline, fwrite, keycode

I'm making this little project with fwrite (long story, and I can't use DB's). The problem is that I wanna do so every time a person submit something, there have to be an 
 tag added insted of every key code 13 (new line, enter)
So what can I do to do this? I use JavaScript and PHP to do this.
I have looked at some other postes, but I cant find anything..

Thanks for your support!

Comment: You use what JavaScript? Show your (relevant) code, JavaScript and HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `nl2br` to convert new line to br for a given string in php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php